# Calling timer multiple times has strange result

Tags: c#

When I press button1 the value of tabatas goes from 8 to 1 immediately then the timer1_tick method runs through once correctly`.

```
int goSecondsLeft = 20;
    int restSecondsLeft = 10;
    int tabatas = 8;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (goSecondsLeft >= 0)
        {
            lbGoOrRest.Text = "Go!";
            lbSecondsRemaining.Text = goSecondsLeft.ToString() + " seconds";
            goSecondsLeft--;
        }
        else if (restSecondsLeft >= 0)
        {
            lbGoOrRest.Text = "Rest";
            lbSecondsRemaining.Text = restSecondsLeft.ToString() + " seconds";
            restSecondsLeft--;
        }
        else
        {
            timerGo.Stop();

        }   

    }    

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (tabatas > 0)
        {
            lbTabatasRemaining.Text = "Tabatas remaining" + tabatas.ToString();
            timerGo.Start();
            tabatas--;
        }
    }
```

I put a break point at the line  while(tabataas >0) and kept steping in and each time the while loop executed the value of tabata went down one as expected, but when I run the program it goes to 1 immediatly while the timer1_tick method continues on running.

My working code below:

```
           else
        {
            goSecondsLeft = 20;
            restSecondsLeft = 10;
            tabatas--;
            lbTabatasRemaining.Text = "Tabatas remaining" + tabatas.ToString();
            timerGo.Stop(); 
        }   

    }    

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
            timerGo.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Possibly a thread related issue.

Comment: Why you restart the timer in a loop? also, what is the Interval of the timer?

Comment: interval is 1000ms, I want the code in the time1Tick method to execute 8 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` loop has nothing in it to cause a delay, so it runs through pretty much instantaneously. Maybe you thought `Timer.Start` blocks for some period of time, but it doesn't. It just starts the timer in the background and instantly returns.

Not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but if you want the `tabatas` variable to tick down along the time, remove the loop and decrement the variable in the timer event handler instead.

Comment: I tried decrementing the tabata variable in the tick handler but I don't know how to do it only once it seems to happen every tick.

Comment: I'm guessing this is some kind of interval timer. You should have a place in your code where you reset your go/rest counters to maximum when your "rest" phase ends - maybe decrement it there?

Comment: Yes I changed the code in the else statement to reset the variables and decrement the tabata variable and it works perfectly cheers.